# How do I move a folder to /usr/lib?

Tags: permissions

When I try to move it via WinSCP, it says:

```
General failure (server should provide error description).
Error code: 4
Error message from server: Failure
Request code: 18
```

I'm trying to install Java.

@Compt I need to install Java 7 for my Minecraft server and when I searched on Google for Java 7, a tutorial for doing this came up.

Comment: Have you tried with root permissions? You're doing from the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

From terminal run `sudo mv /path/to/file /usr/lib`

Comment: You may want to elaborate about how this applies to the OP's situation. Remember, the OP is using WinSCP, which is an sftp/scp client for Windows. Also, please note that this only works the folder is on the same partition as `/usr/lib`--otherwise, if using standard command line tools, one must copy (with `cp`) and delete (with `rm -r`, or `rmdir` for an empty folder) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Installing java is easy.

To install the **JRE**. On the command line, type:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

OR

To install the **JDK**. On the command line, type:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

**JRE** = Running Java applications

**JDK** = Developing Java applications

Answer (score 0):

If you need root permissions, type in "sudo nautilus" within the terminal. That will give you access to any folder you need to modify. However, I am curious, why are you trying to install java instead of Open JDK?

Edit: Ahh kk, Minecraft is a pretty sweet game. This answer gives you complete control of your directory, but you'll have to move the folder still.